# JSON object parse object android

Tags: android, json

I will receive a response from the server in this form:

```
{"data":[{"id":22,"name":null,"uuid":"ewfnwofnonf"},{"id":44,"name":null,"uuid":"309r0ddpaso"}]}
```

What i want to do is check the uuid of the device that my device is and get the "id" of the device. 
The uuid will come from this:

```
String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

This is what I tried:

```
final String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
VolleyGetHeaders.getInstance(ProfileSetting.this, finalToken);
VolleyGetHeaders.getInstance().VolleyGETHeaders(domain, "device", new CustomListener<String>() {
@Override
public void getResult(String result) {
    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
            obj = new JSONObject(result);
            if (obj.getString("uuid") == deviceId){

            String userID = obj.getString("id");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             }
             }});
```

Server has successfully gave me a result with a value for uuid, but i have this following error:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for uuid
```

Also is there another way to get the corresponding "id"in my json response for the matching "uuid"?

Comment: Your first tag start with JSONObject named _data_. You can't directly parse _uuid_

Comment: You need to accept the any of the below answer or post what error you are facing again. Accept the answer means supporting other developer to be part in the community in future. this will help you too. Kindly do any of the thing which i said above. That will give you the some badges to you also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are parsing it in the wrong way, please try the following,

```
final String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    VolleyGetHeaders.getInstance(ProfileSetting.this, finalToken);
    VolleyGetHeaders.getInstance().VolleyGETHeaders(domain, "device", new CustomListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void getResult(String result) {
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                obj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray arrData = obj.getJsonArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
                    JSONObject jobj=arrData.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (jobj.getString("uuid") == deviceId) {
                        String userID = obj.getString("id");

                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, since all the answers are similar I will many yours as the answer since you answered the fastest. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that `data` is not just an object that contains a `uuid`. It is actually an array of objects, each of which contains a uuid as a data member. That's why you cannot get any value for uuid when you try to directly access it. Once you find the object from the array with a matching uuid, you can get the id very easily. Try this:

```
JSONObject obj = null;
String userID = null;
try {
        obj = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray arrData = obj.getJsonArray("data");

         for (int i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
             JSONObject jobj=arrData.getJSONObject(i);
             if (jobj.getString("uuid") == deviceId) {
                 userID = obj.getString("id");
                 break;

             }
         }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So when the loop breaks, you will have the id of the object (as userID) for which the uuid matches deviceId

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
    JSONObject obj = null;
     try {
            obj = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray arrData = obj.getJsonArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
                JSONObject jobj=arrData.getJSONObject(i);
                if (jobj.has("id")) {
                    String userID = obj.getString("id");
                }
                if (jobj.has("uuid")) {
                    String userID = obj.getString("uuid");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first get the array and then parse json array, I am pasing the code for you,hope this will help you

```
private void parseJson(String s){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
        if(jsonArray.length()>0){
            for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("uuid:",object.getString("uuid"));
                Log.d("id",object.getString("id"));
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 

1. Please check the below code ..
2. still if you are not getting answer give me URL from where u r fetching data
3. { } object , [] Array 
   4.please check the below code as per your responce in result veriable it should work

   ```
       JSONObject obj = null;
       try {
           obj = new JSONObject(result);
           JSONArray jsonArray=obj.getJSONArray("data");
           for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
               JSONObject jo=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
               String UUID=jo.getString("uuid");
              if (jobj.getString("UUID") == deviceId) {
                   String userID = jo.getString("id");
               }
           }

   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```